# countdown_clock timer with python containing Start, Stop, Pause and Resume button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a countdown clock timer. The issue I am having here is after inputting the time to countdown, it just does not nothing. Not sure what's going on and extra help and code correction would be great and helpful.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class CountdownTimer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Countdown Timer")
        self.root.geometry("500x300")
    
        # Create the time entry fields.
        self.days_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, width=5)
        self.days_entry.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.hours_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, width=5)
        self.hours_entry.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.minutes_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, width=5)
        self.minutes_entry.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.seconds_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, width=5)
        self.seconds_entry.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        # Add labels for the time entry fields.
        days_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Days:")
        days_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        hours_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Hours:")
        hours_label.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        minutes_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Minutes:")
        minutes_label.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        seconds_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Seconds:")
        seconds_label.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        # Create a button to set the time.
        set_time_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Set Time", command=lambda: self.set_time_in_days_hours_minutes_and_seconds(
            days=int(self.days_entry.get()), hours=int(self.hours_entry.get()), minutes=int(self.minutes_entry.get()),
            seconds=int(self.seconds_entry.get())))
        set_time_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        # Create the time label.
        self.time_label = tk.Label(self.root, font=("TimesNewRoman", 25, "bold italic"), text="Time: 00:00:00")
        self.time_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        # Create buttons to start, stop, pause, and resume the timer.
        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="START", font="arial 15 bold", command=self.start)
        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="STOP", font="arial 15 bold", command=self.stop)
        self.pause_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="PAUSE", font="arial 15 bold", command=self.pause)
        self.resume_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="RESUME", font="arial 15 bold", command=self.resume)
        self.start_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.stop_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.pause_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.resume_button.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.count = 0
        self.start_time = None
        self.remaining_seconds = 0
    
        # Start the main event loop.
        self.root.mainloop()
    
    def start(self):
        if self.start_time is None:
            self.start
    
    
    def stop(self):
        self.start_time = None
        self.remaining_seconds = 0
        self.update_time()
    
    
    def pause(self):
        self.pause_button.config(state="disabled")
        self.resume_button.config(state="normal")
        self.after_cancel(self.update_time)
    
    
    def resume(self):
        self.resume_button.config(state="disabled")
        self.pause_button.config(state="normal")
        self.update_time()
    
    
    def update_time(self):
        if self.remaining_seconds > 0:
            minutes, seconds = divmod(self.remaining_seconds, 60)
            self.time_label.config(text="{:02d}:{:02d}".format(minutes, seconds))
            self.remaining_seconds -= 1
            self.after(1000, self.update_time)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Time's up!", "Times up! Your countdown is completed.")
            self.stop_countdown()
    
    
    def set_time_in_days_hours_minutes_and_seconds(self, days, hours, minutes, seconds):
        total_seconds = days * 86400 + hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
        self.remaining_seconds = total_seconds
        self.update_time()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CountdownTimer()
```

Program output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `time_Lable` control is placed over the `set_time_button` control and the inputs have to be validated when you read them.

[image]

The 3 functions need to be defined:

```py
self.after()
self.after_cancel()
self.stop_countdown()
```

and the correct module needs to be imported for the messagebox function:

```py
messagebox.showinfo()
```

Comment: can you kindly paste the updated code so I can understand it better. Made a couple of corrections but not getting the desired result yet. I believe folks will learn from it including myself from the minor error I am missing here. thanks